# XPath for label after input element?

Tags: html, xml, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have difficulty coming up with the right XPath for the label element.

```
<td class="">
    <div class="ui fitted read-only checkbox">
        <input class="hidden" name="id" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="">
        <label></label>
    </div>
</td>
<td class="">Sara Parker</td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//input[@name="id"]/following-sibling::label
```

will select all following `label` sibling elements to `input` elements with `name` attributes equal to `id`.

Answer (score 1):

kjhughes has got the right XPath but if you are open to other locators, a CSS selector is shorter/simpler

```
input[name="id"] + label
```

They both will do the same thing but CSS selectors are faster, better supported, and I think easier to read.